# AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate implementation in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios13, avspeechsynthesizer

Can anyone share how we can implement AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate in SwiftUI.
how we can listen to delegate callbacks methods in SwiftUI app.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

One solution would be to define a class which conforms to `ObservableObject`. The idea would be to use an `@Published` property to enable SwiftUI to make updates to your UI. Here's an example of a simple way to keep track of the state of an `AVSpeechSynthesizer` (I'm unsure of your actual use case):

```
final class Speaker: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var state: State = .inactive
    
    enum State: String {
        case inactive, speaking, paused
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        synth.delegate = self
    }
    
    func speak(words: String) {
        synth.speak(.init(string: words))
    }
    
    private let synth: AVSpeechSynthesizer = .init()
    
}
```

Then, make this class conform to `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` like so:

```
extension Speaker: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didStart utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.state = .speaking
    }
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didPause utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.state = .paused
    }
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
        self.state = .inactive
    }
    
    // etc...
    
}
```

Here, I've simply used the delegate callbacks to update a single `@Published` property, but you could update however you like here depending on your use case. The main point to bear in mind with `ObservableObject`s is using the `@Published` property wrapper for any properties you wish to drive UI updates upon a change in value. Here's an example view:

```
struct MyView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var speaker: Speaker
    
    var body: some View {
        // 1
        Text("State = \(speaker.state.rawValue)")
            .onReceive(speaker.$state) { state in
                // 2
            }
    }
}
```

Note how there's two ways to use `@Published` properties in SwiftUI `View`s. 1: Simply read the value. SwiftUI will update your view upon a value change. 2: Access the `@Published` property's publisher with the $ prefix. Using `View`s `onReceive` method, you can execute code whenever the publisher emits a value.